# Database null field

Tags: mysql, database, null

I'm creating a big database and I'm looking for the answer of the 'Is null equal of any bytes?'

I searched some and found is not but my English is not good enough and I want to be sure did I understand right or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An SQL NULL value reserves one or two bytes in the record directory. Besides that, an SQL NULL value reserves zero bytes in the data part of the record if stored in a variable length column. In a fixed-length column, it reserves the fixed length of the column in the data part of the record.

[This also might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546273/do-null-values-save-storage-space?noredirect=1&lq=1)