# variable-width equivalents to fixed-width data types in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, null

I've read that in SQL Server, fixed-width data types always occupy space whether a column value is NULL or not whereas variable-width data types do not if the column value is NULL. Is there a variable-width equivalent to int, float, datetime, etc.?

Comment: There was a `vardecimal` in SQL Server 2008 - but that's been deprecated again in favour of row/page compression

Answer (score 1):

Q: Are there variable types that don't consume a fixed amount of space?

A: Sure. nvarchar, ntext, image and Document XML come immediately to mind.

Q: Is there anything besides fixed width for types like int, number or datetime?

A: Nope :)

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that the datatypes that start with "VAR" do not take up space on the data page when they are valued NULL. The datatypes for which a VAR version is available are only the character and binary datatypes. All the other ones like INT and DATETIME always take a fixed amount of space independent of their value. See [Space used by nulls in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556363/space-used-by-nulls-in-database)

Comment: There are some exception, e.g. compression, sparse columns and consecutive bit columns.