# Does an empty field take up space in database?

Tags: mysql, database-design, innodb, normalization

I'm trying to be realistic about normalizing a table. I need to decide to add an extra field `VARCHAR(255)` that will be probably empty most of the time, or make a new *mapping table* and store that value plus the relevant *id* there.

My question is, in the first approach, does that empty `VARCHAR(255)` field take up any space in the database?

Platform: MySQL, InnoDB

Comment: You will need a bit of space for the field. Even a 'dbnull' value is a stored (but small) reference.

Comment: @Offler That's not always true, however. Consider SQL Server's sparse column support - NULL values take up no space at all.

Comment: As for normalization: do what makes sense. I have the no NULL-FK policy, but will still allow NULL columns otherwise for "information not provided". Consider someones name: First, Last, and MI. Is it okay if they have a `null` MI? I think so. Not everyone has a middle name/initial.

Comment: @pst thanks for tip for normalisation!

Comment: @pst That is SQL Server >2008. He is asking for MySQL / InnoDB. If you use this, you will have additional informations stored for every non-null collumn ( in MYSQL / INnoDB something similiar is the COMPACT row, think about extra headers, length arguments, and then you get extra used space)

Comment: The space occupied will be so small as to be meaningless for any measure of design quality. Also, what do you mean by normalizing? A schema that is normalized to 5NF will still possibly contain NULLS. 6NF makes it possible to forbid NULL in every column. Treat normalization as a design principle, with trade offs. Don't treat it as a religious tenet.

Comment: @Offler Hence why I *explicitly said* which database. I was pointing out that it is not a universal truth: "not always true".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `NULL`.

In SQL, `null` is different from the empty string `''`.

The `empty string` specifically means that the `value was set to be empty`
While `null` means that the `value was not set`, or was set to null.

Comment: @Mahdi What he says is: use varchar(length) DEFAULT NULL. This will use up minimal space when not set (approx. [2 bytes per row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/556363/space-used-by-nulls-in-database))

Comment: Hey JW. would you like to edit your answer to make Michel Feldheim explanation included? That would helps a lot, I guess.

Comment: @MichelFeldheim: It will actually use only 1 bit per row (or a maximum 1 byte if there are no *other* nullable fields) to store that a column is `NULL`. The length of 0 is not stored when the column is `NULL`.